# Javascript | dynamically loaded script but unable to read/use variables in file right after

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, dynamic, load

Sorry for this question / issue but I have tried to search and research over internet without finding a solution.
I'm **loading a script dynamically with the following code** (in the body of the document there's just a header and footer, and all the scripts below are placed just before ending the body):

```html
    <script src="variables.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script>
        var krama_param = get()
        var scriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')
        scriptTag = scriptTag[scriptTag.length - 1]
        var s = document.createElement("script")
        s.setAttribute("src", "test.js")
        scriptTag.after(s)
    </script>
    <!--<script>
        var krama_param = get()
    </script>
    <script src="input/trikona.js"></script>-->
    <script>
        console.log(hello)
    </script>
```

The script I'm inserting dynamically is supposed to run right where I commented the two in the middle but for some reason is making me become crazy as I'm not able to reference any variable in that document because it's undefined yet.
Based on the debugging I realized **the js file dynamically loaded is processed at the very end of the html script, but why is this happening if I'm telling the script to avoid async functionality** (async=false)?

Is there something else I should be checking or any troubleshooting suggestion anyone has please?

Update: provided new code above with simplifications suggested as per the comments received but still same problem. In addition also troubleshoot with the concept of calling a very simple file (test.js) that I newly created with only one variable (like `var test = "hello"`), super simple, but still unable to read that `test` variable in the script after that `console.log(hello)` and it's returning the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: hello is not defined at`

Update 2: **Could someone please sent me a super simple working example of loading a dynamic script and using a variable in it right after in another script?**

Comment: Why are you using `eval()`? That should be `krama_list[krama_param]`

Comment: `s.setAttribute("async", "false")` should be `s.setAttribute("async", false)`, though you probably don't need it at all.

Comment: Scripts are loaded synchronously by default.

Comment: I suggest you give an ID to the script you want to insert after, and use `document.getElementById()`

Comment: @Barmar I have changed what you suggested and it's right, also removed the `s.setAttribute("async", "false")` as it's not needed, but that doesn't solve the issue, still not getting the variables from the file :(

Comment: If you put `console.log` calls in the dynamic script and the script after it, do they show in the correct order?

Comment: But how do I insert it in the right place with his own ID? I should reference another element of the DOM to be able to put in the right place, shouldn't I?
That's why I'm referencing the last script loaded until that very moment, just before inserting the new script.

Comment: @Barmar I'm placing three `console.log(krama)` in the documents:
1) in the dynamic script,
2) in the script after,
3) at the very end of the file that I'm calling dynamically;

only the third one has the proper values in the variables, despite the first two existing but not with the correct values that one would see in the js file being called in the dynamic script

Comment: My idea was to replace `var scriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script');        scriptTag = scriptTag[scriptTag.length - 1]` with `var scriptTag = document.getElementById("thisscript")` to ensure you're selecting the correct script element.

Comment: But if I reference it like that, how do I insert it in the correct place then? Right now I have this instructions `scriptTag.after(s)`.
Anyway I checked the Elements tab of the console and the dynamic script appears in the correct place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make like that:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <script>
      let scriptEle = document.createElement("script");
      scriptEle.async = false;
      scriptEle.defer = true;
      scriptEle.setAttribute("src", "./t.js");
      document.head.appendChild(scriptEle);

      let scriptEle1 = document.createElement("script");
      scriptEle1.async = false;
      scriptEle1.defer = true;
      scriptEle1.setAttribute("src", "./t1.js");
      document.head.appendChild(scriptEle1);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

content of t.js:

```
console.log(1111);
let test = 1000;
```

content of t1.js:

```
console.log(2222);
console.log(test);
```

Comment: thanks, with this realized that I cannot reference a variable of the dynamically loaded file in a subsequent script, I have to do it right after the end of the dynamically loaded script, otherwise I don't see a way of doing it

Answer (score 0):

Let's try using `document.write` ?

```html
<h1>hello</h1>

<script>
  var url = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js";

  document.write("<scr" + "ipt src='" + url + "'>" + "</scr" + "ipt>");
</script>

<script>
  console.log(jQuery);
</script>

<h2>bye</h2>
```

Comment: please do not use document.write()

Comment: OP wants to load script dynamically then use it right away. That is blocking anyway so I thought might as well do a document.write(). Is it that bad?

Comment: document.write() would overwrite the original html file though, isn't it?

Comment: Only after it's loaded. I don't like this example either, but it's working.